# Selector for hover pseudoclass in CSS

Tags: css, html, pseudo-class

I am trying to add the hover pseudoclass and apply the following styles:

```
Background color must be #eee
Use gray for font color
```

I have done it in two ways:

```
#container :hover {

    background-color: #eee;
    color: gray;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a href="#">link</a>
      <a href="#">link</a>
    </div>
```

The other one is by selecting `div`.

```
div :hover {

    background-color: #eee;
    color: gray;
}
```

The problem is the last one changes the background color but not the font color. I can not understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

To change the font color you have to apply the styles to a tag.

```
#container:hover {
background-color: #eee;
}

#container a:hover{
color: gray;
}
```